# Form - Directive to format all inputs to uppercase

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I need to create a directive that format all form´s input field to uppercase..

I already did this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[uppercaser]'
})
export class UperCaserDirective {

  lastValue: string;

  constructor(public ref: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput(event) {
    const resEventValue = event.target.value.toUpperCase();

    if (!this.lastValue || (this.lastValue && event.target.value.length > 0 && this.lastValue !== resEventValue)) {
      this.lastValue = this.ref.nativeElement.value = resEventValue;

      const evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      evt.initEvent('input', false, true);
      event.target.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  }

}
```

But this one works only for an one input field...

I wanna do this to minimize the alias that I have to put inside each of input fields...

> I need with DIRECTIVE, to repeat as little as possible

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="name" data-upper type="text"/>
<input id="middle" data-upper type="text"/>
<input id="sur" data-upper type="text"/>
```

> Upper the text on a dynamically created element which has an attribute
>   upper and when keyup action happens

```
$(document.body).on('keyup', '[data-upper]', function toUpper() {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Otherwise, you can use a pipe for that.

Comment: I need to do with directive

Comment: Indeed, it's weird to use jQuery for this..  :-s

Comment: This question is similar and seems to have good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825078/directive-to-upper-case-input-fields

Comment: @johey, i got my code from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156582/10647645, so i already tried this answers and dont understand how I can use on my form...

Comment: The harder point is, I want to do this in my form tag and all inputs inside get uppercase

Comment: @heavyrick posted a link to a stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-uppercase-lowercase  You just need to add the attribute uppercase on your form or your input element (it appears to work on both levels). So you'll want something like <form 
 uppercase>

Comment: @johey - This worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: Im thinking something impossible, but I need to make sure if it's impossible... 
Thinking like old desktop apps where we have global parameters like with my exemple here: to convert all of fields to uppercase, have a way to do this in angular? Like text field uppercase, select items uppercase (all items, but on db is lowercase), things like that?