# Automatically convert entered letters into capital [Angular]

Tags: html, angular

I am using angular 4 for my front end.My project consist of many components and each component consist of forms and inputs.

Is there any way to convert each and every letter user entered to my input fields to capital letters.

I think previous answers will not match my project as  I'm having hundreds of input fields I am looking for a easy way to convert every inputs to capital when the user enter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can make this using css.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert input value to uppercase in angular 2 (value passing to ngControl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826325/how-to-convert-input-value-to-uppercase-in-angular-2-value-passing-to-ngcontrol)

Comment: try https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-uppercase-pipe-and-lowercase-pipe-example

Comment: Please be specific and search over internet. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While binding the expression in `view` you can use **[toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)** function

Try this

```
<hello name="{{name.toUpperCase() }}"></hello>    
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

Here is the working [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4mntzv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This works but what I what want is when the user enters the same input field should be converted to capital .

Comment: Yes of course , whatever user enters it should be converted and displayed in capital letters.

Comment: try that link I have mentioned there

Comment: This will convert how it appears on DOM, not actual value

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple css code to convert it.

```
Selector{
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: This will only change the visual appearance of the text. Not the actual value.