# How to permanently disable capslock button in ionic 3 from keypad on mobile?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In my ionic3 app, I want the user to only be able to enter input in lowercase, and so I want to disable the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> button permanently.

I am using `autocapitalize='off'` but it only works for the first time, and the user can turn it off.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Here is my code

```
<ion-item no-padding transparent>
                <ion-label floating>{{data.username}}</ion-label>
                <ion-input required type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="text" autocapitalize='off'></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <!---Input field password-->
            <ion-item no-padding transparent>
                <!--<ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon>-->
                <ion-label floating>{{data.password}}</ion-label>
                <ion-input required type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code of those inputs?

Comment: please check...i have add my code

Comment: Thanks. I've added an answer, please let me know if it works on your end.

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/35826325/5468463

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `directive` to ensure that the content of a input will always be in lowercase. The directive would look like this:

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][lowercase]'
})
export class LowercaseDirective {
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  value: any;

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event) {
    this.value = $event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.value);
  }
}
```

and then you can use it in your inputs, like this:

```
<!-- Notice the lowercase attribute in the ion-input element -->

<ion-item no-padding transparent>
  <ion-label floating>Type some uppercase letters here...</ion-label>
  <ion-input required type="text" lowercase [(ngModel)]="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Please also take a look a this **working demo**: <kbd>[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lowercase-directive)</kbd>

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras, this code is not working, it give error                             Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 11 in [username |lowercase=$event] in ng:///LoginPageModule/LoginPage.html@22:53 ("n-label floating>{{data.username}}</ion-label>
                    <ion-input  required type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="username |lowercase" formControlName="text" >

Comment: Oops, sorry for that! I've updated the answer and also included a Stackblitz project so you can see the input working properly @GAURAV

Comment: @GAURAV were you able to take a look at this answer?