# Make input field default to lowercase in angular

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJs we had a default filter we would apply to an input filed to force lowercase.

This doesn't work in Angular+.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following in the html file:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="_textValue" (ngModelChange)="ConvertToLower($event)">
```

and the following code in component.ts file:

```
_textValue:string;
ConvertToLower(evt) {
    this._textValue = evt.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive that dynamically changes the value of your input to lowercase.

https://www.codementor.io/christiannwamba/build-custom-directives-in-angular-2-jlqrk7dpw

Also you could check out the first answer in this question. It is about changing input to uppercase but the technique is the same.

[How to convert input value to uppercase in angular 2 (value passing to ngControl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826325/how-to-convert-input-value-to-uppercase-in-angular-2-value-passing-to-ngcontrol)