# Angular: How to force uppercase in an input field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm working with angular (typescript) and I have a modelform in html where the user has to insert a code field and a description field.

The code field must always be entered by the user, always in uppercase.

I found and followed this question:
[How to convert input value to uppercase in angular 2 (value passing to ngControl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826325/how-to-convert-input-value-to-uppercase-in-angular-2-value-passing-to-ngcontrol/42728447)

but the last letter that the user inserts remains lowercase however ..
The fundamental thing is that the database always comes in all uppercase (I also put a limit of 4 characters that works properly)
this is my code now, but as written above it does not work properly:

```
<input type="text" id="code" #code class="form-control" formControlName="code" maxlength="4"
                 (input)="code.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()">
```

has anyone found a quick, functional and fast solution?

thank you!

Comment: You could use the onchange event and convert all to upppercase.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can simply add  `oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"` in your `<input>` tag and it will instantly convert any input in your input field to Uppercase.

Comment: Yes, i had just found this solution and I tested it, it works properly!
thank you all!

Comment: (input)="code.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()" doesn't work properly. It capitalizes all letters but the last. @Ali thanks for your solution. Works properly.

Comment: Attention! This solution has a side effect. When you want to change the input in the middle or at the start then the cursor will jump to the end of the line while typing

Answer (score 27):

If you're working with `ngModel`, you can use `ngModelChange` to do it this way with JavaScript's [.ToUpperCase()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp).

```
<input [ngModel]="person.Name" (ngModelChange)="person.Name = $event.toUpperCase()">
```

Answer (score 12):

You could create an Angular Directive which transforms all user input to uppercase.

The Directive extends **DefaultValueAccessor**:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[toUppercase]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => UpperCaseInputDirective),
    },
  ],
})
export class UpperCaseInputDirective extends DefaultValueAccessor {
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) input($event: InputEvent) {
    const target = $event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const start = target.selectionStart;

    target.value = target.value.toUpperCase();
    target.setSelectionRange(start, start);

    this.onChange(target.value);
  }

  constructor(renderer: Renderer2, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    super(renderer, elementRef, false);
  }
}
```

Use the Directive like this on the input:

```
<input name="myTdfInput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" toUppercase>
```

The solution works in both Reactive Forms and Template Driven Forms.

See working demo on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-field-to-accept-only-numbers-czivy3?file=src/app/to-uppercase.directive.ts

Credits for the solution go to: https://twitter.com/BartBurgov (See his tweet here: https://twitter.com/BartBurgov/status/1582394428748009477?s=20&t=RiefRcZ1B8IF42wp2rWzaQ)

Comment: Great approach to consistently transform input to uppercase and also ensures that the cursor position is correctly set aftwards. Especially useful for reactive forms.

Comment: I modified the directive to select all input[type=text] but I can't make it work,  where do I have to specify this directive must be applied to all the inpúts?

Answer (score 10):

Based on @Ali Heikal answer it should be:

```
<input #code formControlName="code" (input)="code.value = code.value.toUpperCase()" type="text">
```

Or use `.toLocaleUpperCase()` if necessary.

Comment: As pointed out by @D_Edet on another answer, this won't capitalize the last letter directly on the model, visually it shows all capitalized but if you check the associated form value it won't. keyup event with form.patchValue works thanks to Sampaguita.

Answer (score 9):

A bit late, but I'm surprised to don't see the css alternative.

Add on the input field:

```
.input-upper{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is purely cosmetic for display purposes, it doesn't change the underlying value. If you need it uppercase for storage, you may need to use one of the other solutions.

Comment: Agreed -- this doesn't deserve a downvote, but a very strong disclaimer. Sometimes, this would be perfectly fine.

Comment: I wanted to display a disabled input as uppercase. This solution works perfectly in my case!

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. I just used keyup and whenever a user adds a character it automatically converts it to Uppercase, not just in the UI but in the model as well.

```
(keyup)="form.patchValue({name: $event.target.value.toUpperCase()})"
```

Comment: In a reactive form, without using `ngModel`, this is simpler for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `pattern` attribute to limit the allowed input. You may also want to assist the user by upper-casing their input.

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]*" name="example" />
```

Comment: Base on my tests with this snippet, pattern doesn't limit the input.  In FF it just flags an error by turning the input box red.  In Chrome, it appears to have no affect.

Comment: what about making first letter capital what the pattern

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with reactive forms as follows:

```js
this.formGroup.get('myInput').valueChanges
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
  .subscribe((value: string) => {
    const sanitizedValue = value.toUpperCase();
    if (sanitizedValue !== value) this.vehicleLpnFormControl.setValue(sanitizedValue);
  });
```

This allows you to perform other sanitisations (like replacing whitespaces) as well with ease.
Additionally, it is also always applied when someone copies something into the input field.

Comment: This solution works and does not violates the Content Security Policy in any chrome app