# How to force uppercase in input depending on a condition and before any validations are triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

- I am using **Angular 8**.
- I want to force uppercase on a field, **depending on a condition**. When the user type something like 'Hi', the value must be changed to 'HI'.
- I want this uppercase applied before the validations are triggered (using reactive forms).
- I don't want to update the input value as uppercase **after** the validations were triggered and use the lowercase value in the validations with a .toUpperCase() because i have a lot of validations and i have other things like 'masks' with Regexp applied on the input field and i need to force uppercase on input value directly. Thus this is not working :

```html
<input #input (input)="input.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()">
```

- I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50447152/12040427) and that's work fine :

```html
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
```

**but not my use case because I don't want to duplicate my  html tags** because i have a lot of configuration on this field and that would lead to repetitive code and i could modify only one input tag and not the other and introduce a bug.... Thus, i don't want to use this :

```html
<input *ngIf="uppercase" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
<input *ngIf="!uppercase">
```

I would use something like this (but that's not working of course) :

```html
<input oninput="if ({{this.uppercase}}) { this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();} ">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1u2vnk)

Comment: please provide a [mcve] as code in the question itself. Stackblitz is great, but it should just be an addition to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After many tests, the solution was pretty easy :

**This solution is NOT working** because the validations are triggered before the changes :

```
(input)="formBlock.forceUppercase ? input.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase() : input.value=$event.target.value"
```

but **THIS is working** (the changed is applied before validations) :

html :

```
(input)="forceUppercaseConditionally(formControl.formControlName, $event);"
```

ts :

```js
forceUppercaseConditionally(formControlName, event) {
    if (this.uppercase) {
        this.formGroup.get(formControlName).setValue(event.target.value.toUpperCase()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below solution.

Use only single `text input` and switch the CSS property `text-transform` on the check and uncheck of the checkbox.

i.e. when you checked the checkbox set the property as `text-transform: uppercase;`. And when you uncheck the checkbox set the property as `text-transform: initial;`

When you validate the form and try to access the value of the input it will return the original value, not the uppercased value.

After that when your validation will pass then you can use the `toUpperCase()` before form submission.

Comment: I explained it in my question : "I don't want to update the input value as uppercase after the validations were triggered and use the lowercase value in the validations with a .toUpperCase() [...]"

Comment: It will show as uppercase in the input box. But actually will return what you write.

Answer (score 0):

ControllValueAccessor is your friend...

If your component implements this interface, then Angular could use this component as a FormControl.

So, I would use a extra component that wraps the input field and the switch to uppercase.
When this component implements a ControlValueAccessor, then you can use this component the same way as you would have used a normal input field.
That means you can use validators and all. Only that the output of this component will be already uppercase.

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             [id]="id"
             [placeholder]="placeholder"
             [(ngModel)]="value"
             (blur)="onBlur()"
             [disabled]="disabled">
```

Typescript:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'shared-uppercase-input',
    templateUrl: './uppercase-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./uppercase-input.component.scss'],
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: UppercaseInputComponent,
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class UppercaseInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() id: string;
    @Input() placeholder: string = null;
    disabled: boolean = false;
    private onChangeFn: (changedValue: string) => void;
    private onTouchedFn: () => void;
    private innerValue: string = '';

    constructor() {
    }

    get value(): string {
        return this.innerValue;
    }

    set value(text: string) {
        if (!text) {
            this.innerValue = '';
        } else {
            this.innerValue = text.toUpperCase();
        }
        if (this.onChangeFn) {
            this.onChangeFn(this.innerValue);
        }
    }

    writeValue(text: string): void {
        this.value = text;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (changedValue: string) => void): void {
        this.onChangeFn = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouchedFn = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }

    onBlur() {
        this.onTouchedFn();
    }
}
```

Now you could use `<shared-uppercase-input>`like a normal text input field, put validators on it, and so on.

Warm regards
Jan

Comment: the problem is I don't want to duplicate my html tags... if i'm implementing this, i must duplicate the <input> tag in my main component into the UppercaseInputComponent

Answer (score 0):

Based on your pseudo code:

```
<input oninput="if ({{this.uppercase}}) { this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();} ">
```

it looks like you want to apply uppercase if `this.uppercase` is true. I would consider making a custom directive for this where you can neatly in template add just for example:

```
<input appUppercase [uppercase]="uppercase">
```

So create the directive, where we pass the boolean value to the directive and based on truthiness we show uppercase or not. Something like:

```ts
import { Directive, Input, SimpleChanges, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appUppercase]'
})
export class UppercaseDirective {
  @Input() uppercase: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.uppercase ? 
     this.el.nativeElement.style.textTransform = "uppercase" 
     : this.el.nativeElement.style.textTransform = ""
  }
}
```

Remember to mark the directive in your appmodule and then it is ready to use!

Here's a simple demo: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highlight-directive-yasrqd?file=src/app/app.module.ts)**

**PS: But this doesn't really affect the form value, it will stay the same as entered, but this is for view only. Of course you can pass the formcontrol to the directive too, and make the changes to it directly. That is, if you need to do it.**

Comment: I already tried something like this, the problem is if i update the form control value, the update will be done after the validations