# What's the right way to make an ngModel input uppercase in angular8?

Tags: angular

What is the right way to ensure that any input that is typed into a text box in angular8 is in uppercase?

I tried applying a style to the input tag

> text-transform:uppercase

, but it looks like while the appearance of text typed into the input box is in uppercase, the value that is actually stored in the

> [(ngModel)]

does not show up as uppercase in uppercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split `[(ngModel)]` into `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`, and convert the input text to uppercase in the event handler:

```html
<input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value = $event.toUpperCase()" />
```

However, there is a problem when a lowercase letter is inserted at the beginning or in the middle of the input text: the caret automatically moves to the end of the text. The technique suggested in [this article](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/input-field-uppercase/) can be used to maintain the caret position, as shown in the following improved code:

```html
<input #txt [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value = convertToUpperCase(txt, $event)" />
```

```js
public convertToUpperCase(input: HTMLInputElement, val: string) {
  // Save caret position
  const start = input.selectionStart;
  const end = input.selectionEnd;
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Restore caret position after returning the converted string
    input.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
  // Return the input string converted to uppercase
  return val.toUpperCase();
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcar5t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way, but without interfering with ng-model directly, I would do like :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: 
        `<input style="text-transform: uppercase" [(ngModel)]="myProperty"> 
        <h1>{{ myProperty }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ _myProperty }}</h1>`,
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
        _myProperty = 'this write in script';
        get myProperty(): string {
            return this._myProperty;
        }
        set myProperty(value: string) {
            this._myProperty = value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-ngmodel-psacve)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use (input) event of input field

in .ts

```
 public value: string = '';
```

.html

```
<div>
    <input [value]="value" (input)="value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()">
</div>
<div>
Value: {{ value }}
</div>
```

Find useful link from here

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding

Answer (score 0):

To write less code, you can use a directive "toUppercase".

You can find the directive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74111888/3216022) written by [spierala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453959/spierala).

You can just use it like this (the model will be in uppercase)  :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" toUppercase />
```